# Trouble getting compute to work on flutter

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart

I am trying to write a function that will run the scrypt function in the background because it is very slow.  I have used to compute before but for some reason this time I get "the function compute is not defined"

```
import "package:pointycastle/pointycastle.dart" as PC;
import 'dart:async';
Future<Uint8List> getKey(Uint8List password,Uint8List salt) async {
  return await compute(computeKey, [password,salt]);
}
Uint8List computeKey(List<Uint8List> param) {
  Uint8List salt=param[1];
  Uint8List password=param[1];

  PC.KeyDerivator scrypt = new PC.KeyDerivator("scrypt");
  scrypt.init(new PC.ScryptParameters(16384, 8, 1, 49, salt));
  return scrypt.process(password);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to import the flutter library `package:flutter/foundation.dart` also the return callback function as parameter requires a `List<dynamic>`
 not a `List<Uint8List>`.

And a quick sidenote: you don't need to `await` the returned future in your code.

Comment: now why do none of the tutorials show this?  But that is exactly the problem.